# Connecting Visual Studio 2012 to Github.com

Tags: visual-studio, github-for-windows

I have added the MS github extension to my project.  Now how do I connect it to my Github account?

Comment: http://gitscc.codeplex.com/documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/01/30/getting-started-with-git-in-visual-studio-and-team-foundation-service.aspx

The above link put me on the right track to integrating Team Foundation Service with Visual Studio 2012.  I misunderstood Git vs Github and will continue to use Github as my ALM for the moment.  The integration of git version control integrated within VS will be worth another look for the next project.