# GIT with VS 2012

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, github

I am trying to use VS 2102 with the Git plugin but cannot managed to go past the selection of a server.  Must I select a Team Foundation Server?  I would like to use GitHUB.  How is this done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507343/using-git-with-visual-studio and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14616632/connecting-visual-studio-2012-to-github-com

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, choose the menu item `Team/Connect To Team Foundation Server...`.

Then in the `Team Explorer - Connect` tab, you can click `Clone`, and enter a URL of a remote repository, on e.g. GitHub:

[image: Team Explorer - Connect with Clone URL]

Then click `Clone` to clone that repository to the path in the textbox below.

Now you can open the solution file in the newly created local repository.